# Refresh JSF component after custom javascript Ajax call

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a custom javascript Ajax call in my jsf page. I capture and process the query string of the XMLHttpRequest in a filter. The filter adds a record to a table in the model.
Now I want the jsf page, without full page refresh, to reflect the updated model in one of the components (a Primefaces data table).

I guess what I need is a custom xmlHttpResponse...

Can anyone tell me how to do this? I'm scared it might be complicated, but I have no choice but to use the custom javascript...

Comment: What would be the difference using a `<p:commandButton action="doProcess()" update="yourDataTableID">` (that comes with ajax call) instead of your custom ajax call? Maybe your problem is using the `<p:commandButton>` (or `<p:commandLink>`) way.

Comment: Please post what you've done and what you're trying to achieve with a custom ajax call here.Ajax is kind of 75% of the reason people use primefaces/JSF. What's the point if you're going to be making custom ajax calls?

Comment: @kolossus For most of what I'm doing, the standard JSF stuff works great. However, I have one large text area within which I have an English text for language study. If a student clicks on a single word, that word is added to their 'learning list'. So, within that one single jsf component are many words, each of which is associated with a javascript ajax call which sends the word, and some additional information, to the server for appending to the database table 'learninglist'. The learning list appears in a dataTable at the right, which I need to refresh!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PrimeFaces [`<p:remoteCommand>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf) is designed for this purpose.

Here's a basic kickoff example for your particular case:

```
<h:form>
    <p:remoteCommand name="updateTable" action="#{bean.updateTable}" 
        process="@this" update="table" />
    ...
    <p:dataTable id="table">...</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

It generates a JS function `updateTable()` which will invoke the `#{bean.updateTable}` method and update the component with (relative) client ID `table`. You just have to call the function `updateTable()` in JavaScript context.

```
updateTable();
```

You can even pass request parameters if necessary, it has to be sent as JS object:

```
updateTable({ name1: "value1", name2: "value2 });
```

No need to fiddle with homebrewed ajax requests and keeping the JSF state in sync.

Comment: So @BalusC if I understand you correctly, I can include another form on the page containing the <p:remoteCommand> tag which will replace my custom ajax call. So, instead of attaching each word to an ajax function, I attach each word to a function which 1) updates the values of the parameters in the <p:remoteCommand..> tab and 2) submits the form encapsulating the <p:remoteCommand..> tab. Is that right?

Comment: Oh fantastic, I'm done!  I just left the existing filter (and custom ajax call) to update the model. Then, in the custom ajax javascript, I called the remoteCommand generated javascript simply to update the dataTable. Works like a charm. I nearly fell off my chair! Thanks @BalusC.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with simple JSF/JS?  Ideally without a dummy button.