# Can't update components created dynamically

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Using Primefaces I pass to a bean the id of the component that the user just clicked. I want the bean to change the style of this component. The relevant part of the bean:

```
public void passIdClicked() {

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String idClicked = (String) map.get("idClicked");

    UIComponent tile = FindComponent.doFind(context, idClicked);

    Iterator<UIComponent> it = tile.getChildren().iterator();

    UIComponent comp = it.next();

    if (comp.getId().equals(idClicked)) {
       HtmlOutputText labelDone = (HtmlOutputText) comp;
       labelDone.setValue("heyyyyyyyyy");
       labelDone.setStyleClass("myStyleClass");
     }
}
```

The modifications are not appearing on screen. What am I missing?

[EDIT] UI Code:
(additional components get created in the "tiles" panelGroup dynamically in an initialization phase. The passIdClicked method modifies one of these components - the one clicked by the user.)

```
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <h:commandButton actionListener="#{bean.createNewTile()}" title="new" value="new"/>
        <p:remoteCommand name="sendNameClicked" actionListener="#{bean.passIdClicked}"/>
    </h:form>

    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="tiles">
    </h:panelGroup>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.tile').click(function() {
                sendNameClicked([{
                        name: 'idClicked',
                        value: $(this).attr('id')
                    }]);
            });
        });
    </script>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Can you show your UI code? If you are using ajax you might just use the update="@this".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kocko answer is absolutely correct, but since you are using Primefaces you can also do it programmatically:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(comp.getClientId());
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to refresh the component(s), so that the styleClass change takes place.

You can, *either*:

- Refresh the whole page.

For example:

```
<f:ajax render="@all" />
```

*Or*

- Refresh a particular component:

For example:

```
<p:someComponent id="componentId">
   ....
</p:someComponent>
...
<f:ajax render="componentId" />
```

Comment: thanks! I added the detail of the UI code. Not sure where I should put the ajax tag?

Comment: I think I got the solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893025/refresh-jsf-component-after-custom-javascript-ajax-call  I need to add the following to the remoteCommand: process="@this" update=":tiles"